# Consume Java Web Service from .Net Asynchronous

Tags: java, .net, web-services, asynchronous

Is it possible to consume a Java web service (actually it is build by WebMethods from softwareAG)  **asynchronously** from a .NET client (using c#)?

I don't know whether this java WS is supporting Asynch or not, we can't edit it, so what we are able to do is to adjust on client-side (.net)

Thanks in advance for your insight

Comment: **Asynchronously** only means that you are not waiting for an response in the calling thread. Create a new thread that requests the web service, receives the response and invokes an event to signal the calling thread that the request has finished. If you are able to access an WSDL file, than you can create async stubs (`Begin...`) using Visual Studios "Add Service Reference...", so there is nothing left for you to do than calling the `BeginWebService` method instead of `WebService` (or whatever your service is called).

Answer (score 0):

A web service, no matter what its implementation, can be consumed by any client capable of making the appropriate HTTP request.  So if the web service is SOAP based, your .NET client just needs to connect and POST the appropriate XML.  This is easy to do.

It's not clear to me what you mean by asynch.

If the service is written to be asynch, it would imply that it immediately returns a response and mechanism to allow the client to come back and check for the response.  You should check with the service owner.

Your client is certainly free to call the service in an asynch way.  Delegates have been part of .NET for a long time.  I believe the [modern idiom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228969.aspx) uses asynch events.

Comment: Hi @duffymo, thanks for your response. I want the client to be able to  call the service without waiting reponse (blocked), if the service actually return response (synch) can my client ignore it and decide that it really doesn't need that response so it doesn't need to wait. So the service is NOT written to be asynch but i want to consume it by asynchronous call.